# Setting up docker container so that I can access python packages on ubuntu server

Tags: python, docker

I'm new to using Docker, so I'm either looking for direct help or a link to a relevant guide. I need to train some deep learning models on my school's linux server, but I can't manually install pytorch and other python packages since I don't have root access (sudo). Another student said that he uses docker and has everything ready to go in his container.

I'm wondering how to wrap up my code and relevant packages into a container that I can push to the linux server and then run.

Comment: How to create Dockerfile is entrypoint for you. Install Docker, make Dockerfile, build simple image and then run container. Have fun!

Comment: @wrogrammer I need to do pip installs, but my linux server doesn't even have pip installed and I can't install it myself. How can I bundle pip?

Comment: Are you thinking about using pip inside Dockerfile or using pip to install Docker ?

Comment: Docker is instilled on the linux server, but pip isn't. So I'd like to use pip inside the Dockerfile to install pytorch and some other tools.

Comment: You don't need installed pip on Linux Server. Please read about how works Docker and what is Docker container. Prepare Dockerfile with for example debian and then install there what you want for example python-pip3 with pip3 to install pytorch.

Comment: Yes I understand that. Take a look at this example: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#dockerfile. It shows a pip install of requirements.txt - how is pip being incorporated into the container? Where do you specify that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172721/discussion-between-jonnyd42-and-wrogrammer).

Comment: It's not good example. Inside Docker container you can install what do you want. Please to understand it create new Dockerfile, then install debian and python-pip3. To install tools and modules inside the container you dont need pip3 installed locally.

Answer (score 2):

To address your specific problem the easiest way I found to get code into a container is to use git.

1. start the container in interactive mode or ssh to it if it's attached to a network.
2. `git clone <your awesome deep learning code>`. In your git repo have a `requirements.txt` file. Change directories into your local clone of your repo and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`
3. Run whatever script you need to run your code. Note you can easily put your `pip install` command in one of your run scripts.

It's important to remember that docker containers are stateless/ephemeral.  You should not expect the container nor its contents to exist in some durable fashion.  This specific issue is addressed by mapping a directory on the host system to a directory in the container.

Side note: I first recommend starting with the [docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/).  You can easily skip over the installation parts if you are working on system that already has docker installed and where you have permissions to build, start, and stop containers.

Comment: According to Docker tutorials, installing git in containers is generally frowned upon (downloading the master branch just using wget would be better)

Comment: @cricket_007 could you explain why or share a link to the part of the tutorial that talks about git and docker?

Comment: Basically installing Git just adds to the image size, when really you can just download the repo directly from `https://github.com/{group}/{project}/archive/master.zip`

Comment: I have found a better way than downloading the repo into the image.  Clone the repo onto the host and then map the directory to a path in the docker container.  This avoids having to rebuild the image.  Of course it depends on what one is trying to do.

Comment: Containers are not intended to be sandboxes on a local machine. In production environments, they are intentded to be ran on many hosts, not only one.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have root access (sudo). Another student said that he uses docker

I would like to point out that `docker` requires `sudo` permissions.

Instead I think you should look at using something like [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) or JupyterLab. This gives you the added benefit of code that is backed-up on a remote server